# Give an example of a continuous function $f : [0, ∞) \to [0, ∞)$ such that $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ exists but $f$ is unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Give an example of a continuous function $f : [0,  ∞) \to [0, ∞)$ such that  $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ exists but  $f$ is unbounded.

I have been thinking about this. And I have come to the conclusion that I will need to construct a function, $f$, such that $f$ is a sequence of triangles of increasing height, but decreasing base.
I obviously need $f$ such that both the height of the triangles and the sum of the bases tend to infinity.
But I also need that the $\sum (\text{height} \times \text{base}) \leq \infty $

Comment: The sum of the bases needs to be finite.

Comment: The sum of the bases needs to be infinite to be defined on [0, ∞)

Comment: No. The location of the bases should runt to infinity, but the sum of the lengths of the bases _must_ be finite if you pick triangles, otherwise the integral can't be finite.

Comment: Ah I see what you are suggesting now. We can use up a lot of space  by setting f to be 0. And then there is a lot more freedom! Thanks

Comment: Yes. And if you want something strictly positive, add a quickly decaying function like $e^{-x}$ to it.

Comment: Use height $n$ and base $\frac1{n^3}$, for example

Comment: Base : 1/n^3, Height : 1/n, Gap between trinagles = 1/n - 1/n^3 will suffice. There are obviously so many examples though!

Comment: Does $1/(x^2 + 1)$ work?

Comment: @sidht: No, it is bounded.

Comment: @DanielFischer Your comment about sum of bases needing to be finite is surely incorrect. If the triangles are of increasing height then you are, but we could choose the triangles to have decreasing small height 'a sufficient amount of the time' and 'sufficient increasing height' the rest of time and it would all work out fine!

Comment: @jonwilson Okay, pedantically "the sum of the length of the bases of the triangles with height $\geqslant \varepsilon$ must be finite".

Answer (score 3):

Building off your idea, but allowing most of the triangles to have zero height (otherwise it will not converge): Choose some divergent series. I'll assume we're dealing with the harmonic series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$. The nth triangle will have base $\frac{1}{n}$.

Now in general, start with $f \equiv 0$, i.e. suppose the general triangle we have is degenerate. But let the $2^n$th slot have a triangle of height $2^{n/2}$.

Or more generically: have some shape that has area $1$ from $0$ to $1$, then some shape that has area $\frac{1}{2}$ from $1$ to $2$, $\frac{1}{4}$ from $2$ to $3$, smoothing as necessary. You can make your function $0$ as much as you want, but you need to make your shapes get taller. You can think of fitting a triangle of height $k$ in the $k$th slot, making the base the necessary width to give area $\frac{1}{2^k}$ in that slot.

You can do many more along these lines.

Comment: I'd love to see a pretty elementary example, if one exists. Can you modify a sine function so it gets a broader base and sharper peaks? Something weird like $(\sin x^2)^x$

Answer (score 3):

Successive triangles is definitely the way to go (for example, choosing the $n$th triangle centered at $n$ with height $n$ and width $1/n^3$ does the job) but mixtures of distributions provide regular examples which are rather natural (to probabilists, at least...). Thus, consider
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}n\,\varphi(n^3(x-n))\cdot\mathbf 1_{x\geqslant0},
$$
where $\varphi$ is any multiple of any regular PDF such that $\varphi(0)\ne0$, for example,
$$
\varphi(x)=\mathrm e^{-x^2}.
$$
Then $f(n)\geqslant n\varphi(0)$ hence $f$ is unbounded at infinity, the function $f$ is smooth, its support is the full halfline $[0,+\infty)$, and $f$ is integrable since
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx\leqslant\int_\mathbb R\left(\sum_{n\geqslant1}n\,\varphi(n^3(x-n))\right)\,\mathrm dx=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{n^2}\cdot\int_\mathbb R\varphi(x)\mathrm dx.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $$f(x)=x^2\exp(-x^8\sin^2 x)$$

as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460762/showing-a-lebesgue-integral-exists-while-another-doesnt).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same desire expressed in [dfeuer's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469184/give-an-example-of-a-continuous-function-f-0-mapsto-0-such-that/469204#comment1009812_469189).

From the answers to [Integral of $\cos^{n}(x)$ on $[0,2\pi]$ for $n$ a positive integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/125591/) and Stirling's approximation we get $$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^{2n}x\,dx\sim\dfrac{2\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt n}.$$  Using this fact, we can show that $f(x) =  x |\cos x|^{x^5}$ is an example.  Note that $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\int_{2\pi k}^{2 \pi(k+1)} x|\cos x|^{x^5}\, dx.$$ Because $t\mapsto t$ is increasing and $t\mapsto |\cos x|^t$ is decreasing for each $x$, we can bound each summand as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{2\pi k}^{2 \pi(k+1)} x|\cos x|^{x^5}\, dx
& \leq\int_{2\pi k}^{2\pi(k+1)} 2\pi(k+1)|\cos x|^{(2\pi k)^5}\,dx\\
& \leq 2\pi(k+1)\int_{2\pi k}^{2\pi(k+1)}|\cos x|^{2k^5}\,dx\\
&= 2\pi(k+1)\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^{2k^5} x\,dx\\
&\sim \dfrac{C}{k^{3/2}},
\end{align*}$$
where the last step follows from the afore mentioned result, and $C$ is a constant independent of $k$.  Hence $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx<\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Building up on the idea of triangles presented by many users, I have found a simple enough function...

The idea is that the bases of the triangles, when taken as a series should diverge to $\infty$, while the individual terms converge to $0$. But the series of areas of triangles should converge to some finite quantity. One natural candidate for the bases of triangles is the sequence $1/n$.

Then $\sum 1/n > \infty$, and taking the heights to be $\sqrt{n}$ (with alternating signs of course), we get the areas to be $$\dfrac{1}{2},-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}},\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{3}},-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{4}} \cdots$$
It is well known that the series $\sum (-1)^{n+1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$converges and so we are done.
[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMpeI.png)

Answer (score -1):

Let $f= \cases{ x^{-1/2} , & $[0,1)$ \\ x^{-2} , & $[1,\infty )$ }$, then $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx = 3$. Is that what you are looking for?

EDIT: In the spirit of mixedmath: Let $Tr(x,h,w)=\max (1-|2x/w -1| , 0 )h$. Then let $h_i=i^{1/4}$ and $w_i=1/i^{2+1/4}$. Let $f=\sum_{i=1}^\infty Tr(x-i,h_i,w_i)$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty f(x) dx = \int_0^\infty\sum_{i=1}^\infty Tr(x-i,h_i,w_i) dx= 1/2\sum_{i=1}^\infty i^{-2}=\pi^2/12
\end{equation}
with questionable convergence.

Comment: Your function is undefined at $x=0$.

Comment: What about $ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} (x+\epsilon )^{-1/2} ,  [0,1) $?

Comment: Gummi: That makes no difference. You are either leaving $f(0)$ undefined or calling it $+\infty$, so it is not an example.  Note that a continuous function from a closed, bounded interval in $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ is bounded, so whatever the example, it will be bounded on each interval of the form $[0,M]$.